# Ef code first migrations on server:Cannot open database "blahblah" request by the login. The login failed

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

There are a million threads like this but none where the answers worked.I'm trying to get this database set up on my server (which I can remote into), but every time I try and run the web app I get this error. Why is code first not creating the database? Here's some relevant code.

Connection string in web.config

```
<add name="Context" connectionString="Data Source=Server\Instance;Initial Catalog=myDb;Trusted_Connection=false;User Id=User;Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Global.asax relevant portion

```
Context context = new Context();
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, Configuration>());
        context.Database.Initialize(true);

        if (!WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Initialized)
            WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("BaseContext",
                "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Comment: How can CodeFirst create the database if it cannot even login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're using integrated Windows authentication, you need to create a SQL Server login for "yourUser\ASPNET" on your SQL Server - or change your connection string to something like :

```
<add name="Context" connectionString="Data Source=Server\Instance;Database=myDb;Id=User;pwd=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The login failed error is inside sql server error. Try if you have SQL Managment Studio logged using your data in connection string - Context.

I only thinking, but when you migrating your database recreate your user sql account and rester sql server.

Or

Try create new user by SQL Managment studio and then try usgin this data to connection string.

Check when you create user account, is not checked user must changed password first time.
I think my idea resolved your problem :)

Comment: I can login to the database through SSMS with the credentials I've supplied in the connection string. The problem is code first isn't creating the database so the login fails when the app runs.